# Use DateTime to print name of day from a date?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use DateTime to go through a list of dates, and find the days of week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesdat, &c.) that are most often associated with each date in the list.

I am trying this:

```
contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol

contents.each do |row|
times = contents.map { |row| row[:regdate] }
target_days = Hash[times.group_by { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').wday }.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}.sort_by{ |k,v| v }.reverse]
puts target_days
```

I get:

```
{1=>6, 2=>5, 5=>4, 6=>2, 0=>1}
```

From what I understand wday will represent each day as 0(sunday), 1(monday), &c. I am stumped on how to convert this into the actual name of the day? Or how can this be converted to the abbreviated name (Sun, Mon, Tue, &c.)?

Also, I'm not positive the above is returning the correct days. Looking at my list, there are six dates for 11/12/2008. November 12, 2008 was a Wednesday — but it looks like it is showing that the most common day, with a count of 6, is Monday. So, I'm not sure that this is really counting the correct day of the week.

Can someone please explain why what I am doing doesn't seem to be counting the correct day of the week, also — how to convert this to the name of the day and abbreviated name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `wday` integers to full names using `Date::DAYNAMES` and abbreviated names using `Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES`:

```
Date::DAYNAMES[3]
#=> "Wednesday"

Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[3]
#=> "Wed"
```

**Update**

As far as your algorithm goes, it looks right to me:

```
require "date"

times = [
    "4/25/2014 00:00", # Friday
    "4/21/2014 00:00", # Monday
    "4/22/2014 00:00", # Tuesday
    "4/20/2014 00:00", # Sunday
    "4/22/2014 00:00", # Tuesday
    "4/21/2014 00:00", # Monday
    "4/21/2014 00:00", # Monday
    "4/19/2014 00:00"] # Saturday

target_days = Hash[times.group_by do |time|
      DateTime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").wday
    end.map do |key, value|
      [Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[key], value.count]
    end.sort_by do |key, value|
      value
    end.reverse]

puts target_days
#=> {"Mon"=>3, "Tue"=>2, "Sat"=>1, "Sun"=>1, "Fri"=>1}
```

I would double check the contents of the file, and then step through the algorithm to see what's going wrong.

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks! And I figured out why it was getting the wrong day of week --- I accidentally had %Y where it should have been %y.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = Time.new(2000)

# The full weekday name
puts time.strftime("%A")
# Saturday

# The abbreviated name 
puts time.strftime("%a")
# Sat
```

See [Time.strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more details. `DateTime` has the same implementation.